# name 'user' is not defined, django forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have an User abstract user model with some fields including mnemonic which is a CharField and an image that's an ImageField.

I want to be able to use the mnemonic as a confirmation field to change the image in a form but I can't get the old mnemonic in the clean() method and so I get name 'user' is not defined.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    mnemonic = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, default='default.jpg', upload_to='pictures')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['image', 'mnemonic']

    def clean(self):
        super(UserUpdateForm, self).clean()
        mnemonic = self.cleaned_data.get('mnemonic')
        if mnemonic != user.mnemonic: # name 'user' is not defined, line where I need to get the old mnemonic
            self._errors['mnemonic'] = self.error_class([
                'The mnemonic is wrong!'])
        return self.cleaned_data
```

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p class="article-title"><b>Profile Info</b></p>
        {{ profile_form }}
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

```
def ProfileView(request):
    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        profile_form = UserUpdateForm()

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: Also share your view related to this.

Comment: I've edited my post and added the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error `user` is not defined makes complete sense since `user` is not defined anywhere.

To resolve the problem, try to use `self.instance.mnemonic` which will give the current instance's mnemonic so:

```py
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['image', 'mnemonic']

    def clean(self):
        super(UserUpdateForm, self).clean()
        mnemonic = self.cleaned_data.get('mnemonic')
        if mnemonic != self.instance.mnemonic:
            self._errors['mnemonic'] = self.error_class([
                'The mnemonic is wrong!'])
        return self.cleaned_data
```

> **Note:** Function based views are generally written in `snake_case` not `PascalCase` unlike class based views, so it is better to rename it as `profile_view` from `ProfileView`.